# Edittext layout issue

Tags: android

[image: Screen shot]When i am scrolling through screen , all the text field in that screen shows half text only.. i tried a lot by adjusting size but not getting what is the problem.. can anyone explain me??

Here is my code

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_fname_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/firstname_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_email_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/emailid_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_familyname_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/familyname_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_familyemail_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/familyemail_hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_password_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/inputtext_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_signup_retype_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:hint="@string/retype_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup_sign_id"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_bg"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Provide Screen shot of your problem. No one can test your code without Getting your issue.

Comment: Try changing all EditText's width to WRAP_CONTENT and Still if it doesn't work.. try once removing "@drawable/inputtext_background" from the all LinearLayouts

Comment: MKJParekh: Thanks, I tried by using WRAP_CONTENT and it is because of height i think not because of width but no change in output.. @drawable is my background image so i cant remove it.. any other solution?

Comment: I think there are padding problem in "inputtext_background" file

Comment: Is that inputtext_background a nine-patch? Could it be a problem if it is not a nine-patch?

Comment: NiravRanpara: i have added screen shot now u can check it out..

Comment: @Seema: Put inputtext_background file

Comment: have you tried this one   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @Hasmukh: i dint try adjustPan now let me try this one..

Comment: @Hasmukh: that is also not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give margin on either the linear layout **or** the Edittext. Not on both. The `marginTop` is cutting the edittext's space

Comment: still there is a problem that is margin of layout is for space on layout and margin in edittext is to put space so dat an image black part can be displayed so have to think some other solution..

Comment: @Seema Better you try on gravity and weights rather than padding and margin